# saved model after reloading with tf.keras.models.load_model request different input shape -> untraced functions (embeddings_layer)

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, huggingface-transformers

I am fine tuning a classification BERT model using `transformers 4.5.1` and `tensorflow 2.4.0`. I am using SST2 dataset (using TFRecord format).

I am using the simple way:

```
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased',num_labels=2)

model.summary()
Model: "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  167356416 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_75 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 167,357,954
Trainable params: 167,357,954
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model is trained in the following way:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

learning_rate=5e-5
epsilon=1e-8

# loss
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# metric
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=epsilon)

model._name = 'tf_bert_classification'

# compile Keras model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss,
              metrics=[metric])

model.fit(train_data,
          epochs=1,
          steps_per_epoch=5,
          validation_data=eval_data,
          validation_steps=1)
```

The data looks like that:
train_data

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ({input_ids: (None, 128), attention_mask: (None, 128), token_type_ids: (None, 128)}, (None,)), types: ({input_ids: tf.int32, attention_mask: tf.int32, token_type_ids: tf.int32}, tf.int64)>
```

We can iterate over the data to check again the shape:

```
for i in eval_data:
    print(i[0]['input_ids'].shape)
    print(i[0]['attention_mask'].shape)
    print(i[0]['token_type_ids'].shape)
    print(i[1].shape)
    break


(32, 128)
(32, 128)
(32, 128)
(32,)
```

The model can be trained with a small amount of data.
We can also do prediction:

```
model.predict(eval_data)

FSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=array([[-0.9976097 ,  0.05450067],
       [-0.99764097,  0.05462598],
       [-0.9975417 ,  0.05509752],
       ...,
       [-0.9975057 ,  0.05470059],
       [-0.99738246,  0.0544476 ],
       [-0.9978782 ,  0.05457467]], dtype=float32), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

I can now save the model and reload it:

```
model.save('bert_default')
reconstructed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('bert_default')
reconstructed_model.summary()
Model: "tf_bert_classification"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  167356416 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_75 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 167,357,954
Trainable params: 167,357,954
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now if I try to do prediction with the same data as before I get the following issue:

```
reconstructed_model.predict(eval_data)

    ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (11 total):
        * {'input_ids': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids_1:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=int32>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=int32>, 'token_type_ids': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids_2:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=int32>}
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (11 total):
        * {'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')}
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (11 total):
        * {'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')}
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

I see some Warning when saving the model:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:The parameter `return_dict` cannot be set in graph mode and will always be set to `True`.
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as embeddings_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, embeddings_layer_call_fn, encoder_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, encoder_layer_call_fn, pooler_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses while saving (showing 5 of 1055). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as embeddings_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, embeddings_layer_call_fn, encoder_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, encoder_layer_call_fn, pooler_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses while saving (showing 5 of 1055). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: ert_default/assets
```

Is it the reason while the shape is changed from (-1, 128) to (-1, 5) ?

When training the model I see other warning but people as saying they should be ignire:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:The parameters `output_attentions`, `output_hidden_states` and `use_cache` cannot be updated when calling a model.They have to be set to True/False in the config object (i.e.: `config=XConfig.from_pretrained('name', output_attentions=True)`).
WARNING:tensorflow:The parameter `return_dict` cannot be set in graph mode and will always be set to `True`.
```

How can I fix this issue that appear only when the model is saved ? Should I set some parameters in the config ?

[Edit]
Same issue with `tensorflow 2.5.0-rc3`
Using Huggingface save/load is working fine

```
model.save_pretrained('bert_input')
reconstructed_model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert_input')
```

But this is not what I need for tf.serving.

It seems some class/function definition are not saved with the model so reloading the model will not work. Maybe there are some paramters to set to have this working ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, have you been able to figure it out?

Comment: I didn't have time to try it but I think using:
"tf.saved_model.save(model, path)"
instead of:
"model.save(path)"

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model
Let me know if this help